# Call another php without leaving the defaults

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, web

I am a beginner in web programming and now I am stuck, so I would like to ask for your help.
[image: Site looking]

As you can see, the menu is on the left and next to it the "content" section or something like that where i would like to see tables, etc. What are called by the menus when i click on it. How can I call another php code like u can see below? For example, if you click on the customers, it brings out the customers in a table in the "content" section next to the menu without leaving the page and everything is there just there is now the customers and not the settings or something like that.

My index page Code:

```
<?php
session_start();
// Include login-check file
require_once "login-check.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
  <!-- The meta viewport will scale my content to any device width -->
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!--Favicon-->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="icons/favicon.png">
  <!--Title-->
  <title>Learning</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index-sytle.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php
include "sidebar.php";
?>
<div class="users-table">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My sidebar code:

```
<div class="wrapper d-flex">
<div class="sidebar">
<ul>
</ul>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Föoldal</a></li>
    </ul>
    <small class="text-muted px-3">Ügyfélkezelés</small>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="./adminView/viewCustomers.php"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>Ügyfelek</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-file"></i>Ajánlatok</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>Rendelések</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="logout.php"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>Kilépés</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my viewCustomer code which i want to see on the same page "index.php", but near the menus.

```
<?php
/* Database credentials. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'test');

/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

// Check connection
if($conn === false){
die("Nem sikerült csatlakozni..." . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if(!$result){
die("Rossz kérés: ") . $conn->error;
}

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
echo $row["id"];
echo $row["username"];
}
?>
```

Thank You guys for your help!

Comment: You may wan't to use AJAX to dynamically change the content. Btw, what do you mean with "Without leaving the page"? You don't want to refresh it or dont want the url to change?

Comment: Well, you either rely on a server side implementation, using plain links in the menu and reload the whole page for each click in the menu taking care to render the menu such that the last clicked entry is open and highlighted. Or, much better, you use client side logic (so javascript) to capture the click event and load the content of the right side by means of an AJAX request to the server.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is doing it via the include() and function using data retrieved from the url.

```
if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
$q = $_GET["page"];
$qa = explode('/', $q);
$page = $qa[0] ?? "home";


//check if a file with the filename retrieved from the $_GET["page"] exists
if (file_exists($pathToFile . $page . '.php')) {

    //if it does, include that file
    include($pathToFile . $page . '.php');

} else {
//$_GET["page"] is not set, redirect to somewhere it is or.
}
```

Now you link to you index file only and setting the $_GET["page"] to whichever file you wish to retrieve.

Should look something like this:

> index.php?page=filename

the $_GET["page"] here will contain the value "filename"